# Orderby query does not work for custom fields even with meta query

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query

I have written the following query to fetch a list and want to show the list of names in ascending order.

I was earlier trying to pass `meta_key` and `meta_value` as arguments but it would not give the sorting correctly.

After trying `meta_query` I'm still stuck with the same problem.

```
$connected = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'connected_type'    => 'posts_to_pages',
        'connected_items'   => get_queried_object(),
        'nopaging'          => true,
        'post_type'         => 'attorney',
        'attorney_category' => 'partner',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => - 1,
        'caller_get_posts'  => 1,
        'orderby'           => 'order_clause',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'        => array(
            'order_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'Last name',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The following is the error I get when I print the query result:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Are you sure the key name you used is correct: "Last name"? Or is it something like wpcf-last-name? Please check in database - wp_postmeta table.

Comment: yeah i checked in database and key name is proper.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `order_clause` is an acceptable [orderby parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). According to the documentation you will need to add a `meta_key` to your query if you want to `orderby` a `meta_value`.

I have amended your query to display *attorney* posts where the custom field key *Last name* is present regardless of the custom field value. `orderby` is set to `meta_value` which refers to the `meta_key` which has been set to *Last name*.

```
$connected = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'connected_type' => 'posts_to_pages',
    'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
    'nopaging' => true,
    'post_type' => 'attorney',
    'attorney_category'=> 'partner',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
    'meta_key'  => 'Last name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
  )
);
```

Presuming your custom field is actually called *Last name* this query should work.

You could add a second `orderby` parameter such as `title` as a fallback:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value title'
```